# Can "take off" be used instead of "remove" in this context

Tags: word-usage, phrases

A told B:
Take off(to mean "remove") the grill,I have to clean it. I looked it up online.

Is the use of "take off" instead of "remove" natural?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in many contexts, "take off" can substitute for remove:

> Before we start the MRI, I'm going to need you to **take off/remove** all jewelry and anything metal on your body.
>
> To fix the regulator, you first have to **take off/remove** the protective cover.

One exception is for something like *edit*, in which case use "take out":

> Before we release this year's corporate report, please **take out/remove** any references to the previous CFO, since we don't want to remind anyone of that scandal.

or *extract*:

> The process **takes out/removes** the particulate matter from the solution, so that it may be easily refined.

There may be other exceptions as well.

Answer (score 1):

Take *off* X means remove X from something that it is  *on*. Usually it is used in the context of clothes. ([Take off](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/take-off_1#take-off_1__1))

So you can *take off* clothes and jewellery because you previously *put them on* (they are on you).

A grill is supposedly an inherent part of a bigger thing (cooker, or barbecue), not just something that is put on something else. In that case, "remove" is more appropriate.